# Creating a box around a figure that includes the tabbing environment

Tags: latex, frame, figure, tabbing

I would like to create a frame or box around my LaTeX figure, which consists of code formatted with the tabbing environment. My code looks something like this:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tabbing}
\texttt{void method(I, T, E)} \{ \\
\ \ \texttt{some code}<\emph{some pseudo code}>();\\
...
\end{tabbing}
\caption{The caption for the figure}
\end{figure}
```

I have tried using various box and frame commands, both within and without the figure, but LaTeX typically responds with "Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item" or "Not in outer par mode".

How can I create a box around the contents of my figure?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend posting at [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com) in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use [the `mdframed` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed). It is quite customizable, I defined a style to illustrate its use:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\mdfdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=yellow!20
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{mdframed}[style=mystyle]
\begin{tabbing}
\texttt{void method(I, T, E)} \{ \\
\ \ \texttt{some code}<\emph{some pseudo code}>();\\
...
\end{tabbing}
\caption{The caption for the figure}
\end{mdframed}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```